# join between two dataframes with multiple similar columns in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I want to use joins for my usecase.
I have two dataframes ( actually data from cassandra table data)

**shop DF -> id1 is primary key**

**item -> id1 and id2 are primary keys ( composite primary key)**

data looks like below

**shop DF**

```
id1|t_id|reserve_lead_time|
+---+----+-----------------+
|  1|   2|                1|
|  2|   3|                2|
|  3|  34|                2|
|  4|   5|                3|
|  5|   6|                4|
|  6|   2|                4|
+---+----+-----------------
```

**item DF**

```
id1|id2|t_id|                  e|purchase_flg|
+---+---+----+-------------------+------------+
|  1|  2|   2|2022-10-13 10:00:00|           1|
|  2| 23|   5|2000-10-23 23:00:00|           1|
|  3| 22|  26|2000-10-13 01:00:00|           0|
|  4| 21|  27|2000-11-11 12:00:00|           0|
|  5| 25|  21|2000-12-01 02:00:00|           1|
|  6| 27|  23|2000-12-01 02:00:00|           0|
+---+---+----+-------------------+------------+
```

I would like to have results something like below ( want to fetch reserve_lead_time from shop table based id1 in both tables )

```
id1|id2|t_id|                  e|purchase_flg|reserve_lead_time |
+---+---+----+-------------------+------------+-----------------|
|  1|  2|   2|2022-10-13 10:00:00|           1|     1           |
|  2| 23|   5|2000-10-23 23:00:00|           1|     2           |
|  3| 22|  26|2000-10-13 01:00:00|           0|     2           |
|  4| 21|  27|2000-11-11 12:00:00|           0|     3           |
|  5| 25|  21|2000-12-01 02:00:00|           1|     4           |
|  6| 27|  23|2000-12-01 02:00:00|           0|     4           | 
+---+---+----+-------------------+------------+------------------
```

I am trying to use leftoutter join so that I will have data of lead_reserve_time of id1 from item table

`item = item.join(shop.select('reserve_lead_time', 'id1'), item.id1==shop.id1, how='left')`

But the above code is appending both reserve_lead_time and id1 to item DF

If I use below code

`item = item.join(shop.select('reserve_lead_time'), item.id1==shop.id1, how='left')`

its returning below error as we have t_id in both dfs

`AnalysisException: Reference 't_id' is ambiguous, could be: t_id, t_id.;`

Could someone help how to achieve this? I would like to add reserve_lead_time to item DF
from shop DF based on id1

Comment: if the keys are of same names across both dataframes, you can pass the list of column names as key -- e.g., `data1_sdf.join(data2_sdf, ['id1', 't_id'], 'left')`

Comment: actually I want to filter based id1 itself, I don't want to use t_id. any idea how can I do it

Comment: just use a single column name in the list, and you can rename the matching column names in the right dataframe before joining